# Is &= operator short-circuited in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Consider:

```
BOOL ok = somethingOrOther() ;

ok = ok && somethingElse() ;
```

vs:

```
BOOL ok = somethingOrOther() ;

ok &= somethingElse() ;
```

In both cases, the intention is for `somethingElse()` to *not* be evaluated if `ok` is already `NO`. This is because C does [short-circuit boolean evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

I wish I could have written:

```
ok &&= somethingElse() ;
```

instead. But that seems illegal.

My hunch is that `&=` will evaluate `somethingElse()` whereas `&&=` (had it been legal) would have not.

Anyone knows?

Comment: Is your question essentially "is it true that `&&=` would not evaluate `somethingElse()`? While it's a good question, I have a hunch such a hypothetical is off-topic here. However, `&&=` does work in the way you describe at least in Ruby.

Comment: Yes, remember that `&` and `&&` are two quite different operations.  `&` is bit-wise and will never "short-circuit".  If you `&` 3 and 4 you get 15.  If you `&&` 3 and 4 you get "YES" (which is equal to 1).

Comment: No. If you `&` 3 and 4 you get 0. 3 = %b0011. 4 = %b0100. 3 & 4 = 0011 & 0100 = 0000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short-circuiting does **not** apply to bitwise operators - the Standard doesn't define such behavior.

The *logical* AND and OR operators do, however, short-circuit - from C99:

> 6.5.13.4 - Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated

Answer (score 4):

& isn't a boolean evaluation, but rather a bitwise AND operation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND), so I would expect `a &= b` to always evaluate `b`.

Comment: if `a` is 0 then the value of `a &= b` does not *need* to evaluate b as it is already known to be 0 regardless of the value of b. So short-circuit evaluation *could* apply to bitwise `&=`. The question is: does it? Where is that said in the (Obj) C language spec?

Comment: @verec **Short-circuiting does NOT apply to bitwise operators.**

Comment: Yes, short circuiting does not apply to bitwise operations. Short circuiting relies on the fact that evaluation need not happen if we can determine the final value of the expression without evaluating the entire expression. So, `YES || NO` will evaluate to YES every time so we don't even need to look at NO. Now consider `1 + 0`. That evaluates to 1, but we cannot actually determine that based on the fact that the first expression is 1. We have to know the value of the second expression. It's the same for bitwise operations.

Comment: 0 * x == 0 for every x. So NO & anything should be NO. The question is about how many bits of x are taken into account. Bitwise ops take a whole int, so 0 (NO) even extended over 32 bits should still be 0 (NO). So 0 & x, however many bits are set in x should still be 0 (NO).

Comment: @H2CO3 do you have any reference to back your: "Short-circuiting does NOT apply to bitwise operators."? That is what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @verec The reference: the C standard doesn't mention short-circuiting behavior when talking about these operators.

Comment: @H2CO3 Went there: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf [C 11], and the word "circuit" (much less "short-circuit") doesn't even appear in the document :(

Comment: @verec It's not phrased like that. The document says something like this in the case of the logical OR and AND operators: "6.5.13.4 - Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated."

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks! If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bad design. If you're doing error checking, why not just return/bail/handle error when `somethingOrOther` returns `false`? Then you can write

```
if(!somethingOrOther()) {
    /* handle error */
}

if(!somethingElse()) {
    /* handle error */
}
```

Comment: You are answering another question. Think of chaining them: ok &= mightFail1() ; ok &= mightFail2() ; ... ok &= mightFail3() ; This is infinitely more concise and readable than however many equivalent `if` + braces you would have to pollute your code with to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @verec And then why `ok = mightFail1() && mightFail2() && mightFail3();` isn't good enough?

Comment: Try to chain 10 of them? I'd rather have each condition ("step that has to succeed before the next can be checked") on its own line. The way each of your `if (...) {...}` did, but without the noise :-)

Comment: @verec: if you use specific error checking, you can handle errors flexibly depending on what failed. If you are testing 10 nearly-identical conditions, you may want to refactor the common code and avoid duplication.

Comment: Could you stick to the question "does &= support short circuit?" rather than comment on what you do not know? Thanks.

Comment: @verec Could you not downvote a correct answer if you don't understand it? Thanks.

Comment: @H2CO3 Could you understand the question before providing an irrelevant answer?

Answer (score -1):

There's an argument to be made that `&` being bitwise operates on `int`s not on booleans and would not know which of the other (usually 31) bits to ignore.

There's another argument that the `ok` being a `BOOL` the intention  of the code is clearly to deal with a single bit, but then `BOOL` being `typedef`'d as `char` has 8 bits ...

So (Obj)C would really need an `&&=` operator to handle this case so as to force the compiler to consider both sides as a single bit ... Oh my ...

I guess this settles the question, and the answer is: NO. Unfortunately :-(

Answer (score -1):

I ran the following test:

```
- (void)testExampleOther {

    __block BOOL called = NO ;
    NSInteger (^eval)(NSInteger) = ^NSInteger (NSInteger x) {
        called = YES ;
        return x ;
    } ;

    BOOL failed = NO ;
    BOOL ok = NO ;
    for (NSInteger i = 0 ; i < 256 ; ++i) {
        ok &= eval(i) ;

        if (ok) {
            failed = YES ;
            NSLog(@"bitwise & used as logic wise && failed for value: %d", i) ;
        }
    }

    if (!failed) {
        NSLog(@"All values 'x' from 0 to 255 returned NO for:\" BOOL ok = NO ; ok &= x ; \"") ;
    }

    if (called) {
        NSLog(@"BUT x was evaluated even though it did not need to.") ;
    }
}
```

And here's the relevant output:

```
Test Case '-[JFBLib_Tests testExampleOther]' started.
2013-08-21 15:50:47.127 xctest[23845:303] All values 'x' from 0 to 255 returned NO for:" BOOL ok = NO ; ok &= x ; "
2013-08-21 15:50:47.127 xctest[23845:303] BUT x was evaluated even though it did not need to.
Test Case '-[JFBLib_Tests testExampleOther]' passed (0.000 seconds).
```

This seems to validate that:

- the value of `x` in `ok &= x` is irrelevant if `ok` is 0 (NO) to start with
- `x` is evaluated no matter what even when its value cannot make a difference.

Comment: This seems like it should be placed in the question. It's not an answer.